# Autofire any key with Autohotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

This script "autofires" E while holding it down.

```
    $e::
While GetKeyState("e","P")
{
    Random, r, 50, 250
    sleep r
    Send e
}
return
```

Is there a way to globally use this script for any key?

For example: Holding A, will autofire A and Z will autofire Z, etc.

Without manually assigning every possible key on the script.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, [according to Timmy Jim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/399168/how-to-use-autokey-to-keymapping#comment560811_399168), "writing scripts for key mapping software is not about gaming".

Comment: @pppery I wouldn't close due to the lack of community consensus on the matter. We have a long history of allowing [[tag:autohotkey]] questions here, dating more than 10 years ago. This should be discussed in [meta] first.

Comment: @galacticninja see https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16525/should-autohotkey-and-similar-questions-geared-towards-remapping-keys-moving-cur

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$a::
$b::
$c::
$d::
$e::
$f::
$g::
$h::
$i::
$j::
$k::
$l::
$m::
$n::
$o::
$p::
$q::
$r::
$s::
$t::
$u::
$v::
$w::
$x::
$y::
$z::
StringReplace, ThisKeyLabel, A_ThisLabel, $
While GetKeyState(ThisKeyLabel,"P")
{
    Random, r, 50, 250
    sleep r
    Send % ThisKeyLabel
}
return
```

The code uses A_ThisLabel to determine what button is pressed.  I think I can probably setup a loop and use another function to declare the trigger, but I couldn't be bothered because this works :P

Note that the StringReplace is necessary because the $ will show up in the A_ThisLabel.  If you have different hotstrings, like !a or +a or whatever, you'll need to remove the stuff you don't want to Send out.

EDIT:  I can't find how to create the hotkeys using a loop or anything of that sort, but I just added in all the hotkeys manually and that only took me 15 seconds.

Comment: Excelent! Thank you very much.
I'mm teeeeeestiiigg it riight noooooow.